# execute two commands in parallel bash script

Tags: plasma

i have some code like this:

```
#!bin/bash
Xephyr :2 -fullscreen
DISPLAY=:2 startplasma-x11
```

but Xephyr wont stop until you end it with ctrl+c
is there anyway to execute Xephyr :2 -fullscreen and then, after a one second delay, run DISPLAY=:2 startplasma-x11 while Xephyr :2 -fullscreen is still running???

Comment: thanks, this worked very well and is a great solution

Comment: added disown to it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
#!bin/bash
Xephyr :2 -fullscreen & disown
DISPLAY=:2 startplasma-x11
```

Mind that the `&` will echo a job number. If you want you can add a redirect to  `> /dev/null` so it does not show.

The `disown` will keep the process running even after you exit the shell. Otherwise it will get killed.